# NOT NULL constraint failed error on trying to create a register view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

So I've been trying my hand at Django authentication. I tried to create a register view which implements two models the django.contrib.auth.models.User and one custom model which shares a OneToOne relationship with User.

Here's the relevant code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    SapID = models.IntegerField(default=60000000000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserFormRegister, UserForm
# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        users_form = UserFormRegister(data = request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and users_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            userregister = users_form.save()
            userregister.user = user
            userregister.save()
            return redirect('/#/')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        users_form = UserFormRegister()
    return render(request, 'register.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'users_form':users_form},)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('username','password','email','first_name','last_name',)

class UserFormRegister(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('SapID', )
```

SapID is a unique id that each user will have.

Now,when I try to register, the user object gets created but the user profile object doesnt. I get an error saying "NOT NULL constraint failed: foo_userprofile.user_id". What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue, is when you do `users_form.save()`, it actually tries to create at object, and save it to the database where the constraint raises exception. To avoid this, you can use the `commit=False` argument which creates the profile object in memory, but does not save it to the database just yet.

```
userregister = users_form.save(commit=False)
userregister.user = user
userregister.save()
```

[More on `commit=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> This `save()` method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
>   accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
>   then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
>   database. In this case, it’s up to you to call `save()` on the resulting
>   model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on
>   the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the
>   specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.